# Is dispatch_apply synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: objective-c, concurrency

I was told that I could use Grand Central Dispatch to run n processes simultaneously, in an asynchronous fashion.  The documentation said that if the processes were in a for loop, I could use the function dispatch_apply.  But now it's saying

> Note that dispatch_apply is synchronous, so all the applied blocks
>   will have completed by the time it returns.

Does this mean the blocks that are submitted to a queue using dispatch_apply are executed in order?  If so, what is the point of using concurrency?  Won't the slowdown be the same?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`dispatch_apply` is, as stated in the docs, synchronous. It runs a block on the specified queue in parallel (if possible) and waits until all the blocks return. If you want to run a block just once asynchronously, use `dispatch_async`, if you want to run a block multiple times in parallel without blocking your current queue, just call `dispatch_apply` within `dispatch_async`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    dispatch_apply(10, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(size_t size) {
        NSLog(@"%lu", size);
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I want to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of the ***synchronous** `dispatch_apply`* is to ***asynchronously** dispatch the inner loop interations to available parallel processing resources.*  Thus, the overall loop performance may speed up.

Faster loop performance? Very possibly, Yes. (see caveat)

Blocks the thread calling `dispatch_apply`? Yes, just like loop blocks until completed.

For GCD, `dispatch_apply` is **synchronous** since `dispatch_apply` will not return until *all* the **asynchronous**, **parallel** tasks that `dispatch_apply` creates have completed.

However, each individual task *enqueued* by `dispatch_apply` can run as concurrent **asynchronous** tasks *if* the target `queue` is **asynchronous**.

For example in Swift:

```swift
let batchCount: Int = 10 
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0)
dispatch_apply(batchCount, queue) { 
   (i: Int) -> Void in
   print(i,  terminator: "  ")
}
print("\ndispatch_apply QOS_CLASS_UTILITY queue completed")
```

yields unordered output like:

```
0  8  1  9  2  3  4  5  6  7  
dispatch_apply QOS_CLASS_UTILITY queue completed
```

So, `dispatch_apply` synchronously blocks when called, but the "batch" of tasks generated by `dispatch_apply` can run concurrently, asynchronously, in parallel to each other.

Keep in mind the caveat that ...

> the work performed during **each iteration is distinct** from the work
> performed during all other iterations, and **the order in which each
> successive loop finished is unimportant**

Also, note that use of a serial queue for the inner loop tasks will not have any performance gain.

> Although using a serial queue is permissible and does the right thing
> for your code, using such a queue has no real performance advantages
> over leaving the loop in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can get performance speed up by using `gcl_create_dispatch_queue()` with `dispatch_apply()`

For example:

```
@import Foundation;
@import OpenCL;        // gcl_create_dispatch_queue()

int main() {
      dispatch_queue_t queue = gcl_create_dispatch_queue(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, NULL);
      dispatch_apply(10, queue, ^(size_t t) {
           // some code here
      });
}
```

More info:
[OpenCL Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)